# VBA - Search for ID number, delete row

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

What I'm trying to do is grab an ID number from one sheet that we have, search for that ID number in another sheet, and delete any rows that contain that ID number. I would like this to loop so that we can use this with a list of ID numbers that need to be deleted.

Basically we have a list of running entries to delete from a report that we pull every day, and I'm trying to simplify this process with a macro.

This is what I have so far, but I'm having trouble with the loops:

```
Sub Test3()
  Dim vari As String
  Dim finalrow As Integer
  Dim Delete_WS As Worksheet
  Set Delete_WS = Worksheets("Delete")
  Dim AR_WS As Worksheet
  Set AR_WS = Worksheets("Attention Required")
  Dim i As Integer

  finalrow = Delete_WS.Range("L50000").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 5 To finalrow
    vari = Delete_WS.Cells(i, 12).Value
    If AR_WS.Cells(i, 12) = vari Then
    AR_WS.Cells(i, 12).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    vari = Delete_WS.Cells(i, 12).Value
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Since SO is not meant to be a code-writing service, can you [edit] your question with what you've tried so far?

Comment: Sound like you could look into `AutoFilter` =)

Comment: The second parameter should be a single cell.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when you're looping through the sheet where you're deleting from is you're changing the count of rows.  So if you delete one item, you're going to have decrement your finalrow variable by one.